# How to downgrade php 7.2 to 7.0 for magento installation in ubunut 16.04?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-16.04

How to downgrade php version 7.2 to 7.0 for magento 2 in ubunut 16.04 server? I have tried with multiple commands but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by using the below code

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php7.0-common libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-bz2
```

update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0